# React/Redux: On Hover of one Component, change color of all Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, flux

Let `<Word />` be a simple functional component (without state) which takes a few props and displays a word.

```
<Word group={1} />
<Word group={2} />
<Word group={2} />
<Word group={1} />
<Word group={2} /> //There might be many more groups etc.
```

on hover of one of these `<Words />`, I'd like to highlight (change background-color to yellow or something) *all* of the words in the same group. Not just the word hovered, but that word + all the words in the same group.

I wanted to do this with CSS-only originally, but that is apparently not possible. How could I do something like this with React in a minimal fashion?

Comment: You can dispatch an action "HOVER_GROUP" with the "groupId" in the payload. Then, each Word check if it matches with its group and change its backgroundColor to yellow

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
        this.state = {
        currentSelectedGroup: 0,
        value: 0
        };
    this.hoverOff = this.hoverOff.bind(this);
    this.hoverOn = this.hoverOn.bind(this);
    }

    hoverOn(selectedGroup){
    this.setState({
      currentSelectedGroup: selectedGroup
    });
    }

    hoverOff(){
    this.setState({ currentSelectedGroup: 0 });
    }

    render(){
    return(
    <div>
         <Word group={2}
      currentSelectedGroup={this.state.currentSelectedGroup}
      onMouseEnter={ ( ) => this.hoverOn(2) }
      onMouseLeave = {this.hoverOff} />
   <Word group={1}
      currentSelectedGroup={this.state.currentSelectedGroup}
      onMouseEnter={ ( ) => this.hoverOn(1) }
      onMouseLeave = {this.hoverOff}
       />
        <Word group={1}
      currentSelectedGroup={this.state.currentSelectedGroup}
      onMouseEnter={ ( ) => this.hoverOn(1) }
      onMouseLeave = {this.hoverOff}
       />

    <Word group={2}
      currentSelectedGroup={this.state.currentSelectedGroup}
      onMouseEnter={ ( ) => this.hoverOn(2) }
      onMouseLeave = {this.hoverOff} />
      </div>
      )
    }
}

const Word = (props) => {
  let wordClassName =  props.group == props.currentSelectedGroup  ? 'highLight':'default';
  return (
      <div className={`${wordClassName}`}
          onMouseEnter={ props.onMouseEnter }
              onMouseLeave = {props.onMouseLeave}>
      This is my Word Group : {props.group}
      </div>);

  }

export default App;
```

Implement highLight css style as you desired.

Comment: But he said he didn't want use state

Comment: In my implementation, Word can be stateless component with only have props received from parent component.

Comment: Change Word as functional component without state.